# One Marker Animation At A time Google Maps Api 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, animation, marker

I'm working on a Map app and I'm having trouble getting marker animated at a time. I'd like to have it so that when a new marker is clicked, the other's animation is removed. I'm a js noob and have been wracking my head. As of now, I have the markers in an array so that I can remove the animation ..but how can I remove the animation of every other marker when setting the animation for another one?..below is the code I've been playing with

```
for (i in markersArray) {
if (markersArray[i].getAnimation() != null) {
markersArray[i].setAnimation(null);
}
if (marker[i].getAnimation() != null) {
marker[i].setAnimation(null);
} else {
marker[i].setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up coming up with the following code after assigning a unique id to each marker...worked like a charm

```
for( var i in marker ){
marker[i].setAnimation(null);
if( marker[i].id == item.id ) marker[i].setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code that you posted seems fine and if it works for you, great. However, if you only want one marker animated at a time, then it might be more efficient, and easier, to just keep a variable of the last animated marker. For example, in your click event or when you add a marker, you could do something like this:

```
previous_animation.setAnimation(null);
new_marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
previous_animation = new_marker;
```

Comment: It doesn't exactly work for me...I've modified it slightly: `if (marker[i].getAnimation() != null) {
for (i in markersArray) {
    markersArray[i].setAnimation(null);
 }
  } else {
    marker[i].setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
  }`    now when i click a marker thats already animated--they all stop but it still doesn't achieve the desired effect

Comment: Getting a bit closer...can anyone clue me in as to how I can insert a .then statement into the following code bit `for (i in markersArray) {
    markersArray[i].setAnimation(null);
 }
//then switch should go here 
if (marker[i].getAnimation() != null) {

  } else {
    marker[i].setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
  }`

Answer (score 1):

```
var new_marker = this;
if(prev_marker) {
  if (prev_marker.getAnimation() != null) {             
      prev_marker.setAnimation(null);                               
      new_marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
      prev_marker = new_marker;
  }
} else {
  new_marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
  prev_marker = new_marker;
}
```

i prefer @Nick Canzoneri style. Modified it a bit

Answer (score 0):

This is what that i got working, I have my markers in a global variable. Which keeps my markers accessible at all time.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(event) {
    $("input#pickup-"+ marker.id +"").prop('checked', true);

    for (var i = window.markers.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        window.markers[i].setAnimation();
        if(window.markers[i].id === this.id) {
            marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
        }
    };

})
```